# broken words in Microsoft Office Word

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

I am using Microsoft Office Mac 2011. In a paragraph, at the end of each line, words are broken. For example, if I type

```
This is a test sentence. This is a test sentence.
```

It displays like

```
This is a test sentence. This is a te
st sentence.
```

How do I fix? I would prefer

```
This is a test sentence. This is a 
test sentence.
```

Comment: Are the words really "broken" like this or are they hypen-ated? Can you add a screenshot maybe?

Comment: @slhck They are NOT hyphenated. They are just broken.

Comment: I have this problem in the windows 2010 version, when I use the SansSerif font and only when I use that font. I hope this information helps.

Comment: Is this on a laptop by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Check if Hyphenation is on as this could explain the problem ( Make the automatic hyphenation off )